# Ansible: Install tarball via HTTP

Tags: http, installation, ansible

I'd like to extend my ansible playbook to install/verify installation of phantomjs and wkhtmltopdf to my Debian 7 machine. Both programs are available as packed tarballs via HTTP. I know the get_url module, but it doesn't unpack stuff, and if I'd add some shell commands for unpacking and moving the binaries, I suspect each time I run ansible, the tarballs would be downloaded, unpacked and moved again, causing unnecessary network traffic.

How can I solve this? Should I make a .deb file and run that using the apt command, or should I make a new ansible module for installing tarballs, or is there something that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you download specific versions (e.g. `foo_1.2.3.tar.gz` and not `foo_latest.tar.gz`), you can do this by keeping the downloaded tarball :

```
- name: Gets tarball
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: "{{ deploy_user }}"
  get_url:
    url="http://some.host/some_tarball-{{ tarball_version }}.tar.gz"
    dest="/home/{{ deploy_user }}/"
  register: new_archive

- name: Unarchive source
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: "{{ deploy_user }}"
  unarchive:
    src="/home/{{ deploy_user }}/some_tarball-{{ tarball_version }}.tar.gz"
    dest="/home/{{ deploy_user }}/app/"
    copy=no
  when: new_archive|changed
```

Change variables according to your environment.

Comment: Nice, I didn't look closely enough at the get_url docs, they state quite plainly that file are only downloaded if not present at dest. Is there documentation on the `changed` filter, I can only find an example using it, but there's no explanation?

Comment: In fact, `changed` is true if the variable is registered in a task that returns 'changed'. It means that something has "changed" when the task was run. In our case, it means that the file was not present and downloaded. It's not specific to`get_url`, it's a filter you can apply to variables (see http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#id21).

Comment: Note that is the file transfer has borked, you're safe, since `get_url` will only copy the file to the specified destination only after is the transfer is successful.
Note bis: I fixed the unarchive src filename which was wrong

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the unarchive module to unpack your tar file directly from the HTTP source.

`- name: Download and unpack directly from HTTP source
  unarchive:
    src: "http://your_tarball_to_download.tar.gz"
    dest: "/home/dest_directory"
    copy: no`

More information about the unarchive module can be found on the docs http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/unarchive_module.html

Comment: Please update your answer with `version_added 2.0` and keep in mind that `copy=` is deprecated.

Comment: Thank you, Konstantin Suvorov. I am aware that `copy=` is deprecated in favour of `remote_src`. However, using `remote_src=yes` strips the second `/` in `http://` for me and the issue has also been reported by someone else here `https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/4498`